# why 'export $Path=$Path:dir' won't work?

Tags: linux, bash, path, environment-variables

I am just wondering why do we need to use this command

```
export Path=$Path:dir
```

why does the command not look like

```
export $Path=$Path:dir/dir'
```

Comment: because that is how bash works. `$PATH` is expanded by the shell to the value it contains, that is why you cannot use `$` in assignments.

Comment: Case is important. You need `$PATH` not `$Path`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dollar sign `$` is used to *access* a variable, not set it. An easy way to see this is to try and print a variable:

```
test="Hello"
echo test
# prints 'test'
echo $test
# prints 'Hello'
$test="Bye"
# Not allowed
```

Answer (score 7):

If you do this:

```
VAR=value
```

bash sets VAR to "value", creating the variable, if it didn't exist.

If you write:

```
$VAR=value
```

then bash executes this replacing $VAR by its current value. Say, $VAR had the value x, this would produce:

```
x=var
```

**as the command to be executed**. That's why it says "command not found"

However, bash can be told to reinterpret this via `eval`:

```
VAR2=x
VAR=VAR2
echo $VAR2
x

eval $VAR=y
echo $VAR2
y
```